# Convert Integer to Octal using class Integer and multiple methods

Tags: ruby, class, methods, integer, octal

I have a script started but am receiving an error message.  I typically have the right idea, but incorrect syntax or formatting.

Here are the exact instructions given:
Extend the Integer class by adding a method called to_oct which returns a string representing the integer in octal.  We'll discuss the algorithm in class.  Prompt the user for a number and output the octal string returned by to_oct.

Add another method to your Integer extension named "to_base".  This method should take a parameter indicating the base that the number should be converted to.  For example, to convert the number 5 to binary, I would call 5.to_base(2).  This would return "101".  Assume that the input parameter for to_base is an integer less than 10.  to_base should return a string representing the decimal in the requested number base.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
class Integer
  def to_base(b)
    string=""
    while n > 0
      string=(n%b)+string
      n = n/b
    end
  end
  def to_oct
    n.to_base(8)
  end
end

puts "Enter a number: "
n=gets.chomp
puts n.to_base(2)
```

When I run the script I do get the enter a number prompt, but then I get this error message:

```
tryagain.rb:16:in `<main>': undefined method `to_base' for "5":String (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Are you prohibited from using  [Fixnum#to_s](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.3.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-to_s)? If not, that's the way to go. Your pentultimate line should be `n = gets.to_i` (or `n = gets.chomp.to_i`). I'll reformat your code for you.

Comment: There were no extra limitations

Comment: Just use  the builtin method call   n.to_s(8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, do something like this:

```
class Integer
  def to_base b
    to_s b       #same as self.to_s(b)
  end

  def to_oct
    to_base 8    #same as self.to_base(8)
  end
end

 5.to_base 2 #=> "101"
65.to_oct    #=> "101"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to help make this work.  Thanks a bunch Cary and sagarpandy